# найти максимальное значение словаря python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте, интересует такой вопрос. Есть словарь

```
start_dict={
  ('DD2', 'DD3'): 4, ('DD2', 'VD3'): 1, ('DD2', 'VD7'): 0,
  ('DD2', 'VD8'): 0, ('DD2', 'VD6'): 0, ('DD2', 'DD1'): 5,
  ('DD2', 'VD2'): 1, ('DD2', 'R1'): 1, ('DD2', 'VD4'): 1,
  ('DD2', 'VD5'): 0, ('DD2', 'R3'): 1, ('DD2', 'R4'): 0,
  ('DD2', 'VD1'): 1, ('DD2', 'R2'): 1
}
```

Можно ли как-то найти максимальное значение(не по ключу) и после записать весь элемент словаря или несколько элементов если таких несколько c одинаковыми значениями в новый словарь.

Как пример результат работы 1 прохода будет:

```
final_dict={('DD2', 'DD1'): 5}
```

Если я думаю в правильном направлении то это можно сделать через for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [26]: start_dict
Out[26]:
{('DD2', 'DD1'): 5,
 ('DD2', 'DD3'): 4,
 ('DD2', 'R1'): 1,
 ('DD2', 'R2'): 5,
 ('DD2', 'R3'): 1,
 ('DD2', 'R4'): 0,
 ('DD2', 'VD1'): 1,
 ('DD2', 'VD2'): 1,
 ('DD2', 'VD3'): 1,
 ('DD2', 'VD4'): 1,
 ('DD2', 'VD5'): 0,
 ('DD2', 'VD6'): 0,
 ('DD2', 'VD7'): 0,
 ('DD2', 'VD8'): 0}

In [27]: {x: y for x, y in filter(lambda x: start_dict[x[0]] == max(start_dict.values()), start_dict.items())}
Out[27]: {('DD2', 'DD1'): 5, ('DD2', 'R2'): 5}
```

Comment: Квадратичный алгоритм.

Answer (score 6):

```
max_val = max(start_dict.values())
final_dict = {k:v for k, v in start_dict.items() if v == max_val}
```

Answer (score 2):

Линейный однопроходной алгоритм, чтобы найти любой ключ, соответствующий максимальному значению в словаре (результат в новый словарь пишется):

```
final_dict = dict([max(start_dict.items(), key=lambda k_v: k_v[1])])
```

Если наибольшее значение может повторяться, то чтобы найти все соответствующие ключи:

```
max_value = max(start_dict.values())
final_dict = {k: v for k, v in start_dict.items() if v == max_value}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ssd = sorted(start_dict, key=start_dict.__getitem__)
k = ssd[-1]
{k: start_dict[k]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решаю подобную задачу примерно так:

```
import collections

def checkio(text):
  text=text.lower()   
  d=collections.defaultdict(int)
  for c in text:
      d[c]+=1  
  s=sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x :x[1],reverse=True)[0]
  for t in d.items():
      print(t)
  print(str(d.items()))
  return s[0]  





#assert 
checkio("How do yo do")
checkio("One")
checkio("Ooeenn")
 #=='e'
```