# Как после поиска в словаре элементов с максимальным значением, если их несколько, вывести макс или мин уже по ключам?

Tags: python-3.x, словари

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759495/414729

А если несколько ключей с максимальным значением, как вывести один элемент используя уже сравнения ключей (больший из них или меньший)?

```
dic = {}
maxk = {}
with open(r'e:\Downloads\dataset_3363_3.txt') as f:
    st = f.readline().strip().split()
    print(s)
    for a in s:
        b = a.lower()
        dic[a] = st.count(b)
        print(dic)
maxv = max(dic.values())
print(maxv)
for k,v in dic.items():
    if v == maxv:
        maxk[k] = v
print(maxk)
print(min(maxk))
```

пытаюсь что-то наваять, но почему-то даже количество ключей не считает (((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

будет выведен один максимальный результат или вам надо что-то другое?

```
res = max([(key, start_dict[key]) for key in start_dict], key=lambda obj: obj[1])
```

или вам что-то иное требуется?

тогда пожалуйста уточните вопрос, можно даже с примером что есть на входе и что должно получиться на выходе

Если ваша задача:

найти элемент в словаре с максимальным значением и минимальным ключом, то это можно сделать так:

```
start_dict = {"A": 5, "B": 4, "D": 7, "C": 7,}

# найти максимальное значение
max_value = max(start_dict.values())

# найти элемент с максимальным значением и минимальным ключём
res = min([(key, start_dict[key]) for key in start_dict if start_dict[key] == max_value], key=lambda obj: obj[0])

print(res)
```

или так:

```
# найти максимальное значение
max_value = max(start_dict.values())

# найти элемент с максимальным значением и минимальным ключём
res = min(filter(lambda i: i[1] == max_value, start_dict.items()), key=lambda j: j[0])
```

Comment: при нескольких максимальных значениях, вывести ,к примеру, минимальный ключ

Comment: тогда уточните что у вас в качестве ключа выступает, потому что данная задача может быть решена или в 1 строчку или через промежуточный массив в 3 строчки

Comment: в качестве ключей сочетания нескольких англ.бук в разных регистрах. Типа:['TYXc', 'TpbXT', 'TY']

Comment: добавил в конце ответа код - посмотрите

Comment: я не пойму почему у меня count не считает для списка, постоянно 0 выдаёт (